# windows 8 + gentoo uefi grub 2 dual boot

Tags: windows, gentoo, grub2

I've bought a new computer with asus sabertooth 990fx motherboard (well known asus ami bios which can use uefi properly) and installed windows 8 using uefi and gpt to play wine-not-compatible games. Disc now contains partitions:

1. ms efi boot - 100M
2. ms recovery - 100M
3. ms root - 100G
4. unallocated space - 400G

I want to install gentoo by adding partitions mentioned in handbook and no touching MuStdie:

1. ms efi boot - 100M
2. ms recovery - 100M
3. ms root - 100G
4. grub2 efi boot - 200M
5. linux swap - 16G
6. linux root - 30G
7. linux home - 350G

I am new to uefi booting. I was using bios + grup-pc + mbr on old computer. It is possible in this case to use **only one bootloader** thats why I was using chainloader to boot windows (see [handbook](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/HOWTO_Dual_boot))

**Specific question**:
Is it possible to use two uefi bootloaders(ms + grub) in different partitions?

Comment: Could you make your question more specific, at the moment the question is extremely vague. why do you worry that it shouldn't work? have you even tried?

Comment: Ok I will edit question to be more specific

Comment: specific question added

Comment: of course I will try this but I think it is not bad to ask question before: maybe anyone will share his experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've succesfully installed grub 2 to the second uefi partition and both two loader works [via manual](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Grub2) (site is not working now. use [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:84w72Hp87KoJ:en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Grub2%20&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=by) to see). The main trouble for me was to create bootable usb flash with uefi. But when I've done I saw uefi power => uefi + gpt + grub 2 + gentoo + windows 8 = works perfect

But then I saw that each loader is less then 50 megabytes, moved two loaders to the first efi partition and dropped the second efi partition. It works still perfect ^____^